# Storing value of selected result in list that can be exported to JSON

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json

I have an angular app that allows you to search the Spotify API. The results are then listed, and the user can click on a `+` sign to add the selected result to a list on the right. I'm able to add an item with jQuery, but I need to be able to do this with Angular. The resulting list (each with the fields of `track`, `artist` and `album`) from the selected result should be exported into a JSON array object which looks like this:

```
{
  title: 'title of playlist'
  songs: [{
    track: 'title of track',
    artist: 'name of artist',
    album: 'name of album',
    note: 'a note that can be added from the UI',
    customImage: 'url of image that can be added manually'
  }]
}
```

**The Controller**

```
function fetch() {
  $http.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + $scope.search + "&type=track&limit=50")
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data.tracks.items);
      $scope.isTheDataLoaded = true;
      $scope.details = response.data.tracks.items;
    });
}
```

**The Markup**

```
<div ng-show="isTheDataLoaded">
    <div ng-repeat="song in details">
      <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
            <article class="search-result row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <a ng-href="{{song.external_urls.spotify}}" title="{{song.name}}" class="thumbnail"><img src="{{song.album.images[0].url}}" alt="{{song.name}}" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
                    <ul class="meta-search">
                        <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <span>{{song.followers.total}}</span></li>
                        <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></i> <span>{{song.popularity}}</span></li>
                        <li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></i> <span>{{song.type}}</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet">
                    <h3><a ng-href="#" title="">{{song.name}}</a></h3>
              <span class="plus"><a ng-href="#" id="{{song.name}}" title="{{song.name}}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a></span>
                </div>
                <span class="clearfix borda"></span>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Selected results should be appended to the `ul` here:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="playlist">
    <h3>Playlist</h3>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I can use this to add a result to the list, but how can I append the `artist`, `album`, a note and image url to the resulting list?**

```
$('a').click(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $(".playlist ul").append("<li contenteditable='true'>"+id+"</li>");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

add a ng-click to your link

```
<span class="plus"><a ng-href="#" id="{{song.name}}" title="{{song.name}}" ng-click="addItem(song)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a></span>
```

Set the addItem function from your controller as below

```
$scope.selectedSongs = [];
$scope.addItem = function(song){
    $scope.selectedSongs.push(song);
}
```

and your Selected results should be

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="playlist">
        <h3>Playlist</h3>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="song in selectedSongs">
                {{song.name}}
                <div contenteditable='true'>Add Note</div>
                <div contenteditable='true'>Add Url</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's just about it, but how can I add additional fields like `artist` and `album`, as well as a user editable field?

Comment: And does the songs array structure you want is the same with response.data.tracks.items ?

Comment: I need to have two empty fields with keys for `note` and `imageurl`, that will be user editable with `<contenteditable="true">`, so that I can add additional data to the list for each item added from the search results.

Comment: Yes, its the same structure.

Comment: To add empty fields into the selected song you just have to set them in the addItem function. Check the update

Comment: Tried adding them with content, but they aren't showing in the list `$scope.selectedSongs.push("<li contenteditable='true'>Add Note</li>");
        $scope.selectedSongs.push("<li contenteditable='true'>Add Url</li>");`

Comment: Okay try to add these fields directly in the view and then if they got edited, you add content to the selected song. Check update

Comment: I found this to be the solution: `<li>{{song.name}}</li>
            <li contenteditable='true'>Click to add note</li>
            <li contenteditable='true'>Click to add url for image</li>`